# Decrease partition size for ubuntu dual boot

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 dual booted and I don't use ubuntu much. I gave ubuntu a lot of space which I can use for windows. Now I want to reduce the size of the partition. I have unallocated the space which I want to use for windows using Gparted but I can't unmount that free space, neither from windows nor from ubuntu nor by using third-party applications. Please help me use that space in windows as it is my default OS cuz my family uses this laptop and they are not familiar with ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to impossible to move a system partition, because the whole OS is at the beginning of the partition. The easiest way to handle this would be freeing some space at the end of the Ubuntu partition and allocate that free space as a new drive (with a new drive letter) in Windows. Then you'd have a new data partition in Windows.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @zx485 thanks for replying but it didn't work

Comment: +1 for the question. I'm in the same situation. I'm now exploring https://askubuntu.com/q/1016821/48214